# ms access get sum from derived field on forms

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007, derived

I have a derived field in a subform which calculates sum. On the main form I would like to calculate the sum of all the records of the derived field. How would  I do this? Below is the subform calculation.

```
  =DSum("value","lineitems","jobno = " & [JOBNO])
```

In my main form I have tried:

```
  =Sum([JobVALUE])
```

**JobVALUE** is the name of the derived filed in the subform.

I have tried to put the calculation in my main form as well reading from [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207763), however this does not work.

```
=Sum(DSum("value","lineitems","jobno = " & [JOBNO]))
=Sum(DSum("value","lineitems","jobno = " & [frmJobs].[Form]![JOBNOField]))
```